# MS SQL trigger For Saved Old Data to another Table In Updation

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers

I have a Emplyee table as Follow,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjtM6.png

In every Updation(any column Delete,Update) ineed save that details to another table for security purpose.That tbale structure as following.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv1YD.png

I can write a Code in my programe to do this job, but Can i write a trigger to Automatically saved old data to employee updation table using triger?
in a MySql that function availble, I dont Konw about MS SQL.
thank you!

Comment: Can the primary key (service_id) ever change? If not, then it's a simple matter of using a full join on inserted/deleted in a trigger. If yes, it gets more complicated.

Comment: @ZLK No primary key never change? can you show me a example code?

Comment: Well, first, if your logging table is designed specifically for your employee table, then you should add a column to it with the PK (so you can identify which record was altered). I'm not sure how you want to capture the whodunnit information (e.g. do you want to capture the host_name(), the sql login itself or something else entirely?) so I'll focus on the other stuff.

Write a trigger like such:

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER tr_Employee_Update_Delete ON myemployeetable AFTER UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN INSERT mylogtable (Service_ID, changed_column, old_value, change_date, used_ip) SELECT D.Service_ID, C.name, C.prev, GETDATE(), CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') FROM inserted AS I FULL JOIN deleted AS D ON D.ServiceID = I.ServiceID CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Title', I.Title, D.Title), ('Name', I.Name, D.Name), ('Initials', I.Initials, D.Initials)...) AS C(name, cur, prev) WHERE C.prev != C.cur AND C.prev IS NOT NULL; END` You'd need to fill in the rest of the columns manually in the cross apply.

Comment: If you need to capture changes from a null value, you'd need to `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` (or use some variation of ISNULL if you can do that instead) and remove `AND C.prev IS NOT NULL` from the trigger.

Comment: @ZLK - Thank you very much, I will try it now.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest to create audit table similar to original table

```
IF NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Audit]') 
               AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
       CREATE TABLE Audit 
               (Type CHAR(1), 
               TableName VARCHAR(128), 
               PK VARCHAR(1000), 
               FieldName VARCHAR(128), 
               OldValue VARCHAR(1000), 
               NewValue VARCHAR(1000), 
               UpdateDate datetime, 
               UserName VARCHAR(128))

GO
```

Then work on the trigger as below, which can track, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_GUESTS_AUDIT ON dbo.IBIS_UnitSchedule FOR UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @bit INT ,
       @field INT ,
       @maxfield INT ,
       @char INT ,
       @fieldname VARCHAR(128) ,
       @TableName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
       @sql VARCHAR(2000), 
       @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21) ,
       @UserName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @Type CHAR(1) ,
       @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000)



SELECT @TableName = 'dbo.IBIS_UnitSchedule'

-- date and user
SELECT         @UserName = SYSTEM_USER ,
       @UpdateDate = CONVERT (NVARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),126)

-- Action
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
               SELECT @Type = 'U'
       ELSE
               SELECT @Type = 'I'
ELSE
       SELECT @Type = 'D'

-- get list of columns
SELECT * INTO #ins FROM inserted
SELECT * INTO #del FROM deleted

-- Get primary key columns for full outer join
SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
               + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,

              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- Get primary key select for insert
SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+','') 
       + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME 
       + '=''+convert(varchar(100),
coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>''' 
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
       RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
       RETURN
END

SELECT         @field = 0, 
       @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
       SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
               AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
       SELECT @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
       SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit - 1)
       SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
       IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0
                                       OR @Type IN ('I','D')
       BEGIN
               SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME 
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                       AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
               SELECT @sql = '
insert Audit (    Type, 
               TableName, 
               PK, 
               FieldName, 
               OldValue, 
               NewValue, 
               UpdateDate, 
               UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
       + @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
       + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
       + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
       + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
       + @PKCols
       + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.'
                                + @fieldname
                                + ' is not null)' 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' 
                                + @fieldname
                                + ' is null)' 
               EXEC (@sql)
       END
END

GO
```

Comment: Thank  for your time and i will try!